# People learn words, but invent sentences

Tags: theoretical-linguistics

I am trying to find who was the first mentioned that "People learn words, but invent sentences". I read this sentense somewhere. Does anyone has any knowledge about theorist or theory behind this quote?

Comment: I assume it's just a pithy way of stating the fact that although there are only a finite number of words in each language, there is an infinite number of sentences you can make out of them.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a mix of arbitrary meaning of signs from Sausurre with the creativity component of Language we have from Chomsky, if I am correct.
You need to learn how to use and the meanings of a specific word, but can use it multiple times in infinite possible contexts.